# Combine two different lists and then sort by common property on c#?

Tags: c#, linq

I have three objects like this:

```
public class MontoAPagar {
    public int IdComprobante {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int IdMovimiento {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public decimal Monto {
        get;
        set;
    }
    protected MontoAPagar(int idComprobante, int idMovimiento, decimal monto) {
        IdComprobante = idComprobante;
        IdMovimiento = idMovimiento;
        Monto = monto;
    }
    protected MontoAPagar() {}
}
public class PagoInfoDBO: MontoAPagar {
    public int IdPago {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public PagoInfoDBO(): base() {}
    public PagoInfoDBO(int idPago, int idComprobante, int idMovimiento, decimal monto): base(idComprobante, idMovimiento, monto) {
        IdPago = idPago;
    }
}
public class ComprobanteMontoDBO: MontoAPagar {
    public TipoComprobante TipoDeComprobante {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public ComprobanteMontoDBO(TipoComprobante tipoDeComprobante, int idComprobante, int idMovimiento, decimal monto): base(idComprobante, idMovimiento, monto) {
        TipoDeComprobante = tipoDeComprobante;
    }
    public ComprobanteMontoDBO() {}
}
```

Then i have one method that takes two lists `List<PagoInfoDBO> pagos` and `List<ComprobanteMontoDBO> montosDebitoCredito` that performs some calculation over another object that doesn't matter to this question.

What i need to do is to take `pagos` and `montosDebitoCredito` and first.. **group** them by the property `IdComprobante` and then **sort** the grouped list by `IdMovimiento` property.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: It's not clear where the "intersect" part comes in here. It would be helpful to show *real* code instead of pseudo-code, along with an example of input data, expected output, and how far you've got yourself.

Comment: The pseudo-code was only for the class. The intesect is because i need to intersect the lists of class A with the lists of class B by the `Id` property. Maybe intersect is not the right word?

Comment: I don't know whether intersect is the right word or not - it would be easier to tell if you provided the complete code and examples that I asked for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
        static void Main() {
            var pagos = new List<PagoInfoDBO>();
            var montosDebitoCredito  = new List<ComprobanteMontoDBO>();

            var query = pagos.Cast<MontoAPagar>().Concat(montosDebitoCredito.Cast<MontoAPagar>())
                .GroupBy(item=> item.IdComprobante)
                .Select(g=> new {
                            IdComprobante = g.Key, 
                            SortedByIdMovimiento = g.OrderBy(item=> item.IdMovimiento).ToArray()
                        }).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot and see how it works for you:

```
        List<B> listB;
        List<C> listC;
        List<A> concatList = new List<A>();
        concatList.AddRange(listB);
        concatList.AddRange(listC);
        List<A> orderedList = concatList.OrderBy(prop => prop.ID).ThenBy(prop => prop.AnotherID).ToList();
```

Depends what you mean exactly by intersect I guess...

Comment: What would be the difference between `Concat` and `Intersect`?

Comment: `listB.Concat(listC)` won't even compile - they're different types.

Comment: @JonSkeet My mistake, i'll edit with a base class list

Comment: I'm under the impression he just wants them ordered first by ID, then by AnotherID inside of each ID ordering. Same result as grouping by ID, then sorting by AnotherIDm, then flattening.

Comment: I want to take both lists.. group them by `Id` and then sort the result list by `AnotherId`...

Comment: This will order all results in the combined ListB + ListC,  by ID (essentially grouping them). For any with the same ID, it will use the second ordering property, AnotherID, and sort by that. This should accomplish what you're after if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = (from b in listB 
join c listC on b.id equals c.id into group
from g in group.DefaultIdEmpty()
select 
    g.AnotherId, 
    b.somefield, 
    c.anotherfield
).OrderBy(x = > x.AnotherId)
```

**EDIT**

```
var result = (from p in pagos
join m montosDebitoCredito on p.IdComprobante equals m.IdComprobante into group
from g in group.DefaultIdEmpty()
select g
).OrderBy(x = > x.IdMovimiento)
```

Comment: why does this answer the question? What does it do?

Comment: This answers the question because it is the solution to the question.

It pagos and left out joins montosDebitoCredito by IdComprobante into group 'Group' which is then sorted by IdMovimiento.

Comment: Your answer popped up in the low quality queue where I handled it. I left comment to encourage you to not only dump code in an answer but also try to explain a little bit what it does so it is usefull for the OP and other visitors. Your comment text could be a fine start.. good luck.